# Derivative of $\frac{d}{dx}\{\exp \frac{-(x-\mu)^2)}{2 \sigma^2}\}$

Tags: derivatives

How to find derivative of this complex exponent?

> $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\{\exp \dfrac{-(x-\mu)^2)}{2 \sigma^2}\}$$

Comment: $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\mathrm e^{f(x)}=\mathrm e^{f(x)}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\text{exp}{\left(\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}=\text{exp}{\left(\frac{-x^2+2x\mu-\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}=\big(\text{exp}(-x^2)\times\text{exp}(+2x\mu)\times A\big)B$$ wherein $A=\text{exp}(-\mu^2),~~B=\text{exp}(-2\sigma^2)$ are constants and so they do not irritate us to get the derivation in this function. For the rest use @Nik's leading hint in the comment and this fact that $(UV)'=U'V+UV'$. Personally, I like another aswer because the chain rule makes your function simpler in form.

Comment: Nice work, and great sportsmanship, as always!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Using chain rule, $\frac{d}{dx} \exp(-x^2)=\exp(-x^2)\cdot (-2x)$. 
Can you finish the problem now?

By the way the word [derive](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derivation.html) has a different mathematical meaning than what you're referring to here. You should say, 'find the derivative of' or 'differentiate' in this context. Just saying.